# Margin behavior and the browser window in chrome vs firefox

Tags: html, css, margin

I've been developing a responsive wordpress theme where the design calls for a fixed width side bar for navigation. Now, I got that working relatively well, but unfortunately the css/html structure doesn't allow me to really center the actual content relative to the body. To fix this, I added a right margin to the content the same width as the fixed width side bar.

This works totally fine and as expected in firefox, but is broken in chrome.

It appears to be an issue with the way the browser width plays with margins.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <img src="http://panzerphotography.com/include/title.png">
        Some header content
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-content">
            <div class="main">
                <img width="200" height="200" src="http://panzerphotography.com/bridal.jpg"/>

            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
        height:100%;
        background:grey;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}


*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
 }
.container{
    padding-left:300px;
    min-height:100%;
}
.content{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative
}
.inner-content{
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    width:96%;
    max-width:1200px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right:300px;
}

header{
    width:300px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    float:left;
    position:relative
}
.main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Fvqx/1/

If you use firefox, the image resizes correctly and no elements overlap. In chrome, the main content overlaps the header for small screen sizes.

EDIT:
Pretty sure this is a chrome bug. Chrome is calculating a negative value for margin-left:auto; when, as per the spec, it ought to be evaluating 0. Submitted a bug report to chromium here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331454&thanks=331454&ts=1388721494.

Still not convinced that the firefox behavior is 100% correct, but it seems to be more in line with the spec.

Comment: Do you really need this `margin-right:300px;` rule in the `inner-content` class?

Comment: Yes, because that allows me to center the `inner-content` relative to the body (or at least pretend as such). Otherwise, `inner-content` is centered relative to its parent, which looks terribly askew.

Comment: Are you able to show a image(design) with expected results in large and small screens?

Comment: Yes, but the jsfiddle I provided is the basic css required to show the problem. Obviously, the jsfiddle doesn't have any responsive elements. Here is what it should look like (rendered on firefox) Desktop: http://imgur.com/MGi8w6u Large Tablet: http://imgur.com/ve38FB2 Small Tablet: http://imgur.com/zaes2Vl Phone: http://imgur.com/zaes2Vl,ve38FB2,w3y2Mw6#2